# Spark bulks code in log in 'org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException'

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j

I am writing code in Spark (java) and my code seems work but in log shows a Exception about catalyst code generator, I dont know how avoid this error log and I dont know if this affects to results:

```
    19/01/21 08:51:35 ERROR org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator 91: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 277, Column 36: Unknown variable or type "agg_value25"
/* 001 */ public Object generate(Object[] references) {
/* 002 */   return new GeneratedIterator(references);
/* 003 */ }
/* 004 */
/* 005 */ final class GeneratedIterator extends org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator {
/* 006 */   private Object[] references;
/* 007 */   private scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs;
/* 008 */   private boolean agg_initAgg;
/* 009 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec agg_plan;
/* 010 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeFixedWidthAggregationMap agg_hashMap;
/* 011 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeKVExternalSorter agg_sorter;
/* 012 */   private org.apache.spark.unsafe.KVIterator agg_mapIter;
...
/* 277 */       bhj_rowWriter3.write(0, agg_value25);
```

Log show all generated.java class! (code of Spark, not mine) ¿?

In line 277 shows 'agg_value25' var.

Some advise?

Comment: can you provide the code info in this file 'generated.java'? it seems that the issue in a variable type.

Comment: I added line 277 (where is the error of generated.java, class included into Spark package)

Comment: well, i tried to find it somewhere, however it is not exist with this compile exception. Therefor i would recommend you to post your question here https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues/SPARK-25692?filter=allopenissues .It might help and if you got an answer, please post it here. 
thanks